# Select rows when a group of columns depends on another group

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Considering this table:

```
c1       c2           c3         c4          c5       c6         c7
--------------------------------------------------------------------
006      1001        101         0           006     1002        1
006      1001        102         0           006     1002        1
006      1001        102         1           006     1002        1
006      1001        102         1           SVR     1002        1
006      1002        102         1           SVR     1003        1
```

How can I query all the rows based on the `c5`, `c6` and `c7` columns AND all the rows than have the same values on `c1`, `c2`, `c3` and `c4` of at least one of the previous rows.

For example if I want to get all the rows when `c5 = 006`, `c6 = 1002` and `c7 = 1`; The result should be:

```
006      1001        101         0           006     1002        1
006      1001        102         0           006     1002        1
006      1001        102         1           006     1002        1
006      1001        102         1           SVR     1002        1
```

The last row is selected too because `c1`, `c2`, `c3` and `c4` have the same values than the 3rd row.

I've considered using the EXISTS clause, but I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I've been trying to do something like this:      Select * 
from table y
where exists (
  select y2.c1,y2.c2,y2.c3,y2.c4
  from table y2 
  where y2.c5 = '006'
  group by y2.c1,y2.c2,y2.c3,y2.c4) . But apparently this is not working for me. Im new in SQL server and i dont really know how to proceed

Comment: Don't add code or additional information in comments. [edit] your question

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the best solution and I'm not sure it is what you want, but I've tried it on your data and it's worked:

```
select * 
from table
where convert(char, c1) + '$' + convert(char, c2) + 
    '$' + convert(char, c3) + '$' + convert(char, c4) in
        (select convert(char, c1) + '$' + convert(char, c2) + '$' +
             convert(char, c3) + '$' + convert(char, c4) as helperCol  
         from table where c5 like '006' and c6 = 1002 and c7 = 1)
```

Used the `$` as the data separator assuming this char is not used in the data, if it should be changed to some other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exists` clause like this:

```
-- select all records where the column c1-c4 are the same 
-- of some (exists) of the records that are in the "basic conditions" set
select * from MyTable where exists ( 
    select * from MyTable as S where c5 = '006' and c6 = '1002' and c7 = '1' 
    and S.c1=MyTable.c1 and S.c2=MyTable.c2 and S.c3=MyTable.c3 and S.c4=MyTable.c4)
```